# symfony: sfDoctrineRoute pass additional Parameter

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony 1.4 and i have the following Route for my /-Route:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: ContentPage, type: object}
  param: { module: page, action: show}
```

and my show-Action looks like this:

```
class pageActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->content_page = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $this->forward404Unless($this->content_page);
    $this->forward404Unless($this->content_page->getPublished());
  }
}
```

It works but it selects always the first entry of the ContentPage-Table.
Is there a way to pass a "Doctrine-Select-Parameter" inside the routing.yml to use a specific id or so?

Regards,
uhu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `getObjectsForParameters()` method of [sfDoctrineRoute](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/routing/sfDoctrineRoute.class.php).
As you can see, you can use a `method` option in your route definition to define which method of the table model will be used to retrieve the results. You can add your condition in this method.

A second solution is to use the `method_for_query` option to specify which method of the table model will be used to modified the query and retrieve the results.